# find cylindrical multipole coefficients

Tags: potential, multipole-expansion, harmonics

How does one find the coefficients to the cylindrical multipole expansion?

I have the harmonic function $\omega = \dfrac{f(\theta)}{\sqrt{r}}$ where $f(\theta)$ is function with a period of $2\pi$

Given that the exterior multipole expansion is

$\Phi = A \ln r + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{C_k\cos(k\theta)}{r}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{S_k\sin(k\theta)}{r}$

I think the correct procedure to compute $C_k$ would be to solve:

$\int_{r = 0}^\infty\int_{\theta = -\pi}^{\theta = \pi} \omega \cos(k\theta) r dr d\theta = \int_{r = 0}^\infty\int_{\theta = -\pi}^{\theta = \pi} \dfrac{C_k \cos(k\theta)\cos(k\theta)}{r} r dr d\theta$

Similar to the fourier series, the integral $\int_{\theta = -\pi}^{\theta = \pi} {C_k \cos(k\theta)\cos(k\theta)}d\theta = \pi C_k$. However integrating with respect to $r$ does not give a finite answer. What should be the bounds on the integral with respect to $r$?

I do think that because the exterior multipole expansion is not valid at 0, perhaps the bounds should be between some small radius, $\epsilon$, and some large radius, $R$, but am unsure.

Comment: Would this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_multipole_moments#General_cylindrical_multipole_moments ?

Comment: @udrv I've looked at the wiki page but I'm not sure what $\lambda(\rho',\theta')$ is in my case as i'm given the potential field and not the line charges

Comment: The electrostatic potential over there satisfies $-\Delta \Phi = \lambda/\epsilon$ , where $\lambda$ determines $\Phi$. Use this in reverse to find $\lambda$ for your given $\omega$, then apply the formula.

Comment: @udrv thanks for the help, but i'm still confused. rearranging your equation to gives $-\epsilon\Delta\omega = \lambda$. But $\omega$ is a potential so $\Delta \omega = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about it being a harmonic function. In that case, as a separable solution independent of z, $\omega = R(r)f(\theta)$, it must satisfy $\frac{1}{R}\frac{d^2R}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{rR}\frac{dR}{dr} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2f}{d\theta^2} = 0$ (Laplace eq. div. by $\omega$). If we put in your $\omega$, we get $\frac{1}{4r^2} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d^2f}{d\theta^2} = 0$ or $\frac{d^2f}{d\theta^2} = -\frac{1}{4}f$, which solves immediately with periodic conditions for $f = A sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$.

Comment: This shows that your $\omega$ is of the form $\omega_{n} = r^{-n} \sin(n\theta)$ for $n = \frac{1}{2}$, which in itself makes it a harmonic function of order $(0, 1/2)$. I know that harmonics are usually defined for $(k, n)$ with $k$, $n$ integers, but I don't know if you can convert this one to a series over the $(k,n)$ ones. The reason is the singularity in $r=0$, which interferes with a proper definition of orthogonality for the radial functions for $k=0$.